# Is Google Firebase a good alternative for my back-end development?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, web-applications

I recently found out about Google Firebase and how it can be used to help streamline back-end development. I would normally use PHP and MySQL for my back-end development. I have a few different apps that I'll be starting within the next few months, but I would like to develop my back-end a little faster and be able to manage it a little easier. Is Firebase a good alternative if I don't have super complex back-end needs?

Comment: If you want an opinion about usage of Firebase, consider instead posting your questions to firebase-talk. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

because it's a cloud-hosted database.

Usually, the  Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client which is good for your back-end development . Imagine you are building a cross-platform apps for Android, and JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data.

You have everything explained here

[Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)